# How to pivot data for comparison of 2 records with arbitrary ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a pretty simple table like this:

```
create table #People (ID_Num int, Gender char(1), Age int, Name varchar(50))

insert into #People values (7612,'M',38,'Joe')

insert into #People values (2290,'F',17,'Sally')

insert into #People values (93542,'F',38,'Frederica')
```

Each record has an ID, and attributes that are associated with that ID.

Suppose I want to compare 2 arbitrary records, in a report/table that looks like this:

```
Column_Name |Value (For ID 7612) |Value (For ID 93542)
------------------------------------------------------
Gender      |M                   |F
Age         |38                  |38
Name        |Joe                 |Frederica
```

How do I do this? When I try to create something like the above, I get all twisted on the PIVOT / UNPIVOT syntax (do I need both?)

Is there a way to do something like this for any 2 arbitrary IDs? (Meaning, the same code could be re-used for any 2 records, by just plugging the IDs into variables/parameters).

If you want to know why I'm going to all this trouble, instead of just comparing the 2 records as they appear in the table: After I get the pivot part right, I also want to filter, so we only see columns where there is a difference. For example above, I'd show gender and name, but not age. It's a lot easier to filter out the ROWS where the values are different, vs. writing SQL to dynamically select the COLUMNS with a difference.

Comment: This would get ugly with more and more people adding a crazy amount of columns to your table. If you can elaborate on your last paragraph with some examples we can formulate a more elegant solution i'm sure. just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this won't work. In order to pivot you need to know the columns that you want to obtain in a pivoted format. In your case, the arbitrary Id won't let you do that. You can pivot data by years, etc...

I would do this:

```
select * from #people p1
left join #people p2 on p2.id_num<>p1.id_num
```

The take each row and further process it on higher level language (c#, java, python, etc)

Can I ask you why do you need to format your data this way? There probably are some ways to create dynamic SQL for that but in general that is a hack and I would stay away from. Your problem is more likely solvable with the tools/commands you get in SQL and you may need to rephrase it in some way or another. If you need to generate a report I would further massage the data outside SQL to make it fit your report format.

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT also we can achieve above result set based on your table data i have given 
**Normal Pivot**

```
select col,[2290], [7612], [93542] from (
Select 
        T.id_num,
        T.col,
        T.val 
    FROM (
select id_num,col,val from #People
CROSS APPLY (values 
            ('age',cast(age as varchar)),
            ('gender',gender),
            ('name',name))cs(col,val))T)TT
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for id_num in ([2290], [7612], [93542])
) piv
```

**Dynamic Pivot** :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(id_num) 
                    from #People
                    group by id_num
                    order by id_num
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
--print @COLS
set @query = N'SELECT col,' + @cols + N' from (
Select T.id_num,T.col,T.val from (
select id_num,col,val from #People
CROSS APPLY (values (''age'',cast(age as varchar)),(''gender'',gender),(''name'',name))cs(col,val))T)TT
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for id_num in  (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```